# Multiple audio tracks from one source in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, aac, libx265

I'm transcoding my video using ffmpeg but I am unable to figure out how I can get both a 2 channel aac option (downmuxed) and a surround AC3 option in one go.
My current command is:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 \
-c:v libx265 -preset medium -crf 21 -pix_fmt yuv420p10le \
-tag:v hvc1 \
-c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 320k \
-c:a ac3 -b:a 512k \
movie_10bit.m4v
```

But I only get surround out of this.
All help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 11):

Go with the `-map` option to `ffmpeg`. Suppose input stream `0:0` is the video stream and `0:1` is the audio stream (find out by `ffmpeg -i input.mp4`). Use `-map` to create one video stream and two audio streams in the output:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 \
-map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:1 \
-c:v libx265 -preset medium -crf 21 -pix_fmt yuv420p10le \
-tag:v hvc1 \
-c:a:0 libfdk_aac -b:a:0 320k \
-c:a:1 ac3 -b:a:1 512k \
movie_10bit.m4v
```

`-c:a:0` and `-c:a:1` describe the codec for the two audio streams.

Comment: Thank you! This was very useful but now I notice that I get AAC and AC3 both in stereo. How can I get AAC to be stereo and AC3 to be surround (5.1-6ch)?

Comment: @IanBauters I have limited experience with surround but I think you should try with `-ac:1 6`.